# Which kind of USB device attached - equivalent for the full functionality of lsusb on macOS?

Tags: usb

Neither 1) System Information, 2) `ioreg -p IOUSB -w0 -l`, 3) `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` nor 4) [jlhonora](https://github.com/jlhonora/lsusb)'s "[lsusb](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/23803)" for macOS
(`brew update && brew tap jlhonora/lsusb && brew install lsusb`) tell me ***which kind of USB device*** is attached like the [Linux command `lsusb`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/lsusb8.html):

> DESCRIPTION lsusb  is  a  utility for displaying information about USB buses in the system **and the devices connected to them.**

Use case: I want to know what kind of USB device is attached (e.g. USB 2 or 3) - not which type of port the device is connected to. Per [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/604169/598643):

[image: USB ?]

Comment: ::peeks under the hood of `lsusb` and dreams of reworking it for macOS:: https://github.com/gregkh/usbutils/blob/master/lsusb.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may take a bit of extrapolation, but use the value from "Speed" in `system_profiler`

For example, looking at the Logitech USB receiver (for my mouse and second keyboard):

```
$ system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep Logitech -A5
          Vendor ID: 0x046d  (Logitech Inc.)
          Version: 12.01
          Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec
          Manufacturer: Logitech
          Location ID: 0x14200000 / 3
          Current Available (mA): 1000
          Current Required (mA): 98
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

Looking at the "Speed" value, it tells me that it's a USB 1.1 device.  Doing the same lookup for my Seagate FreeAgent Go USB disk, I get the following:

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep Seagate -A5
              Vendor ID: 0x0bc2  (Seagate LLC)
              Version: 1.48
              Serial Number: 2GE7WLWG
              Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
              Manufacturer: Seagate
              Location ID: 0x14320000 / 23
              Current Available (mA): 1000
              Current Required (mA): 100
              Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
              Capacity: 500.11 GB (500,107,861,504 bytes)
```

It tells me it's got a speed of 480Mb/s which is a USB 2.0 device.

You don't have to output all that extra data, I am just using it for illustration purposes, instead you can just narrow it down to the line containing the speed value:

```
$ system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep Seagate -A5 | grep Speed
              Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
```

For reference, [USB speeds/specs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_1.x) are as follows:

```
USB 1.x - 12Mb/sec
USB 2.0 - 480Mb/sec
USB 3.0 - 5Gb/s
USB 3.1 - 10Gb/s
```