# Boot Camp Assistant can't install Windows after partition made and booted to USB installer?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp

How do I install a bootable copy of windows on my older macBook Air with [Boot Camp Assistant](https://support.apple.com/boot-camp)?

1. Per Apple's list of supported devices, "[Use Windows 10 on your Mac with Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990)" I have an 11" mid-2012 2GHz i7 macBook Air with a 500GB SSD (running macOS Sierra 10.12.5) which I would like to install a bootable Windows partition on and make use of Windows 10.
2. Per Windows recommendation I downloaded the "[Windows 10 Anniversary Update ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)" selecting the "Windows 10" edition (not "N" or "Single Language"). Note to self: [other options for Windows .iso files](https://www.howtogeek.com/186775/how-to-download-windows-7-8-and-8.1-installation-media-legally/)
3. Per "[How to install Windows using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468)" & "[Install Windows on your Mac using a USB hard drive or flash drive](https://help.apple.com/bootcamp/assistant/6.1/#/bcmp09f5f773)" I mounted a [USB 2.0](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/285371/216401) drive ([SanDisk Cruzer](https://www.sandisk.com/home/usb-flash/cruzer-glide)) and started the Boot Camp Assistant process. (Note: I do also have a Time Machine backup).
4. After setting up the USB installer, partitioning the Boot Camp disk and once rebooted into Windows 10, I see the "BOOTCAMP" partition but there is a warning message saying the driver's are unavailable. Rescanning the available volumes for the driver's does nothing. I am unable to proceed.

I was able to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> restart into recovery mode and remove the Boot Camp partition. This resulted in the startup process ending at the `No bootable device, insert boot disk and press any key` screen. I then used <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>restart</kbd> to get back into my macOS 10.12.5 partition, where I [reset the startup disk in System Preferences](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/17343/216401).

Per this 2016 9TO5Mac article and video, "[How to install Windows 10 on your Mac using Boot Camp Assistant](https://9to5mac.com/2017/01/23/how-to-install-windows-10-mac-boot-camp-assistant-partition-video/)" I was under the impression that I could install Windows 10 and use the "[Windows 10 Insider](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3038430/windows/how-to-join-the-windows-10-insider-preview-program.html)" option without a registration key. See also the article, "[You Don’t Need a Product Key to Install and Use Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/244678/you-dont-need-a-product-key-to-install-and-use-windows-10/)" for some notes on the limitations of the free "Insider" install.

1. Do I need to purchase windows 7 first, then install that and **then** upgrade with the Anniversary Edition installer (and then upgrade to Windows 10 Creators)?
2. Is there a more appropriate .iso file I should be using?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad, I just needed to take the extra step of formatting the Boot Camp drive to NTFS:

[image]
(per: https://www.howtogeek.com/186907/how-to-install-windows-on-a-mac-with-boot-camp/)